# data.table: create new columns with lapply

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

i have a data.table and want to apply a function to on each subset of a row.
Normaly one would do as follows: `DT[, lapply(.SD, function), by = y]`

But in my case the function does not return a atomic vector but simply a vector.
Is there a chance to do something like this?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(9)
DT <- data.table(x1=letters[sample(x=2L,size=6,replace=TRUE)],
                 x2=letters[sample(x=2L,size=6,replace=TRUE)],
                 y=rep(1:2,3), key="y")
DT
#   x1 x2 y
#1:  a  a 1
#2:  a  b 1
#3:  a  a 1
#4:  a  a 2
#5:  a  b 2
#6:  a  a 2

DT[, lapply(.SD, table), by = y]
# Desired Result, something like this:
# x1_a x2_a x2_b
#    3    2    1
#    3    2    1
```

Thanks in advance, and also: I would not mind if the result of the function must have a fixed length.

Comment: Do you want x1 & x2 to have the same levels?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta For simplicity lets asume so.

Comment: it's simpler without it.  Otherwise, the levels need to be modified.  I was asking based on how you were creating your data.table.  (ie, sampling from the same set, but due to the random sampling, not all values are represented.  Should the non-values be 0, or should they simply be ignored)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to unlist the table and then coerce back to a list:

```
> DTCounts <- DT[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, table))), by=y]
> DTCounts

   y x1.a x2.a x2.b
1: 1    3    2    1
2: 2    3    2    1
```

.

---

if you do not like the dots in the names, you can `sub` them out:

```
> setnames(DTCounts, sub("\\.", "_", names(DTCounts)))
> DTCounts

   y x1_a x2_a x2_b
1: 1    3    2    1
2: 2    3    2    1
```

---

Note that if not all values in a column are present for each group
(ie, if `x2=c("a", "b")` when `y=1`,  but `x2=c("b", "b")` when `y=2`)
then the above breaks.

The solution is to make the columns factors before counting.

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, is.factor)]

## OR
columnsToConvert <- c("x1", "x2")  # or .. <- setdiff(names(DT), "y") 
DT <- cbind(DT[, lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols=columnsToConvert], y=DT[, y])
```

Comment: you might want to add `with = FALSE` in `DT[, y]`?? or `DT[, list(y)]`

Comment: @Arun, not in this case.   `DT[, "y", with=FALSE]` will produce a `data.table`, equivalent to `DT[, list(y)]` (minus the key).  On the other hand, `DT[, y]` is returning a vector similar to `DT$y`

Comment: Yes, but I am wondering why would one want to convert it to a vector, because then, `cbind` will coerce it to a `data.frame`. Is that what you want? `class(cbind(y=DT[, y], DT[, lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols=columnsToConvert])) ## [1] data.frame`

Comment: @Arun, yes great point!  I originally had the `y=DT[, y]` as the second argument, and moved it forward to make it more obvious. I overlooked the implications on cbind. Great call, thanks. I've edited the answer.

Comment: (+1) Much better than mine!